# Purpose of fork with single bidon mount and no eyelets?

Tags: touring, accessories, rack

I saw a fork that had a single bidon mount on each blade, midway down, and no eyelets on the dropouts. I don't understand the use of this. I was under the impression that any front rack would need an eyelet for mounting the bottom of the rack. Alternatively, a bottle cage needs a pair of mounts. So what's the function of this? Seems that there must be some other kind of mounting hardware. What is it?

Here's my representative sketch:

[image: Crap sketch]

Comment: A) There are racks which utilize the front axle instead of requiring eyelets.  B) There are "handlebar baskets" which clamp to the handlebar but utilize stabilizer bars running down to the fork arms.

Comment: @danielrhicks please answer in answers

Comment: @DanielRHicks could you link to an example rack and basket?

Comment: This isn't an eyelet for a bidon cage but either for a front rack or for a mudguard. Quite common on touring bikes.

Comment: Note: eyelet = little hole; islet = little island.

Comment: Please fix the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mount is for pannier racks that sit low on your fork. In the absence of this mount I have seen a bracket used, but this is more secure. The rack also mounts using the front axle.

[image: front pannier rack]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how old your bike is, it may be a front light fitting.

[image: http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4135/4860956376_3ee58a3a2a_b.jpg]
and
[image: http://oldroads.com/oldroads_files/459_3.jpg]

So theres a chromed bracket that bolts into the hole, and the old lamp gets slotted on top of it.

Here's a modern take on the same mounting location, letting you use a normal handlebar light but mounted lower down.

[image: Modern take on it https://cdnmos-bikeradar.global.ssl.fastly.net/images/news/2017/11/21/paul-gino-light-mount-4-1511274622264-1j5e18aq5q16i-630-80.jpg]